# Variable in php object property name

Tags: php, oop, variables

I have got a php class named request. Is it possible to access one of it's properties with a variable in the name of a property?

Something like this:

```
$i=4;
$request->option_$i = 'something';
```

Thank you

Comment: [Demo](http://ideone.com/PQKYZO)

Comment: Why why why? This kind of thing should be in an array, not a dynamic variable name. Yes you *can* do it, but it's really bad coding practice. Just turn it into an array and reference it as `$request->option[$i]`.

Comment: Thank you, for your answer!

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like this:

```
$request->{'option_'.$i} = 'something';
```

Comment: *Yeah, yeah, but your scientists were so preoccupied with whether or not they could that they didn't stop to think if they should.* - Dr. Ian Malcolm